# How to scroll a table down to bottom

Tags: ios

I know that when you tap on the status bar on top, it will scroll the table all the way to the top.

Is there a similar way that can scroll it all the way to the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way to scroll to the bottom of a table.

It would be up to the developers to add that specific function to their table view.